# Mapping a new column to a DataFrame by rows from another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, performance, numpy, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame `stations` with index as id:

```
id    station     lat     lng
1     Boston      45.343  -45.333
2     New York    56.444  -35.690
```

I have another DataFrame `df1` that has the following:

```
duration   date       station   gender
NaN        20181118   NaN       M
9          20181009   2.0       F
8          20170605   1.0       F
```

I want to add to `df1` so that it looks like the following DataFrame:

```
duration   date       station   gender  lat     lng 
NaN        20181118   NaN       M       nan     nan
9          20181009   New York  F       56.444  -35.690
8          20170605   Boston    F       45.343  -45.333
```

I tried doing this iteratively by referring to the `station.iloc[]` as shown in the following example but I have about 2 mil rows and it ended up taking a lot of time.

```
stat_list = []    
lng_list []
lat_list = []
for stat in df1:
  if not np.isnan(stat):
        ref = station.iloc[stat]
        stat_list.append(ref.station)
        lng_list.append(ref.lng)
        lat_list.append(ref.lat)
  else:
        stat_list.append(np.nan)
        lng_list.append(np.nan)
        lat_list.append(np.nan)
```

Is there a faster way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this would be best solved with a merge which should significantly boost performance:

```
df1.merge(stations, left_on="station", right_index=True, how="left")
```

This will leave you with two columns `station_x` and `station_y` if you only want the station column with the string names in you can do:

```
df_merged = df1.merge(stations, left_on="station", right_index=True, how="left", suffixes=("_x", ""))
df_final = df_merged[df_merged.columns.difference(["station_x"])]
```

(or just rename one of them before you merge)